# TYPO3 TypoScript: How to wrap a TEXT value for IMAGE altText

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I need to build an IMAGE TypoScript which will display the altText and titleText in the resulting `<img>` HTML attributes.

This TypoScript does not work for some reason:

```
image = IMAGE 
image {
    file =  fileadmin/user_upload/myimage.png
    params = class="image-embed-item" loading="lazy" 
    titleText = TEXT
    titleText.value = My Image Title
    titleText.stdWrap.wrap = Bildtitel {|}
    altText = TEXT
    altText.value = My Image Alt Text
    altText.stdWrap.wrap = Alt-Text {|}
    imageLinkWrap >
}
```

The resulting image HTML is.

```
<img src="/example.com/fileadmin/_processed_/3/8/myimage_6a870622f1_c1450d54f1.png" width="134" height="198" class="image-embed-item" loading="lazy" alt="Alt-Text {TEXT}" title="Bildtitel {TEXT}"
```

TYPO3 processes it as `{TEXT}` instead of using the value added to the `TEXT`. "{My Image Title}" should have been in the .

I have already tried to use `stdWrap`, `wrap`, `wrap2`, `wrap3`, `innerWrap` and `outerWrap` without any success.
I am sure that there must be a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up different possibilities:

`altText`is of type "string /stdWrap". So, in the simplest case, you can assign a string to the property and define a wrap:

```
image = IMAGE 
image {
    altText =  My Image Alt Text
    altText.wrap = Alt-Text |
}
```

If you have to do advanced stuff in your altText, you can use a `cObject`:

```
image = IMAGE 
image {
    altText.cObject = TEXT
    altText.cObject.value = My Image Alt Text
    altText.cObject.stdWrap.wrap = Alt-Text |
}
```

Because of the order of rendering, it would also be possible to not wrap the string directly, but the whole cObject:

```
image = IMAGE 
image {
    altText.cObject = TEXT
    altText.cObject.value = My Image Alt Text
    altText.wrap = Alt-Text |
}
```

And last but not least, `stdWrap`-function itself has a `stdWrap`-property, so you could also do:

```
image {
    altText.cObject = TEXT
    altText.cObject.value = My Image Alt Text
    altText.stdWrap.wrap = Alt-Text |
}
```